# GIT assume-unchanged rebase issue

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have tried

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged myFile.txt
```

myFile.txt is tracked by git. Assume I made changes to myFile.txt and "some other files" in repositories and commit the "some other files". But when I try to rebase/merge I get "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge".

I know that is how **git update-index --assume-unchanged** works but is there an alternative other than manually checkout the file and merge the other changes?

I want git to ignore some of the files in my local but I still want the files to be present in remote repo. Can I configure my local git to ignore these files during merge/rebase???

Answer (score 0):

No, and using `--assume-unchanged` is very dangerous to your files. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Is there an alternative to --assume-unchanged?

Comment: That was the `No` part of the answer. Either a file is tracked or it is untracked, there is no middle-way. Move your checked in `my-config.xml` to `my-config.xml.sample` in the repository and ass `my-config.xml` to `.gitignore`. Or make the code that uses the file search for an additional `my-config-local.xml` that overrides the checked in file.